# Morfologik stemmer conflicts with ascii folding

Tags: solr, lucene, polish

I have a Solr-5.5.1 with the following filters in my field analyzer definition:

```
    <filter class="solr.MorfologikFilterFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
```

It usually works great, but for some words there's a problem, for example with `Poznań`. It's a city name, but the stemmer recognizes it as a polish noun with the base form `poznanie` and that's what gets indexed. Now ASCII folding should make sure that when searching for `poznan`, documents with `poznań` will match. But `poznan` is not recognized by stemmer as `poznanie`, so there is not match.

Any ieas how to resolve this?

My idea for a workaround would be to make stemmer always retain the original token, so that `poznań` turns into `[poznań, poznanie]` instead of just `[poznanie]`. Is there an easy way to achieve this? Is there a reason it doesn't work like this by default?
I didn't find anything about it in the javadoc for [solr.MorfologikFilterFactory](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_5_1/analyzers-morfologik/org/apache/lucene/analysis/morfologik/MorfologikFilterFactory.html).

Comment: what are the analyzer at query time ? Can you post relevant parts of your schema.xml?

Comment: I have only one analyzer definition, so query analyzer is the same. I even confirmed that when I remove MorfologikFilterFactory in this one place the `poznan->poznań` matching works fine.

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple implementation for my workaround idea: make sure the stemmer receives each token along with its ascii-folded form. This can be done with an additional ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory:

```
    <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" preserveOriginal="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.MorfologikFilterFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
```